# Serializing form and use labels and paragraphs as keys in array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form that at the top is basic, just some input fields. But further down is a list with categories, questions and three possible answers for every question using switches (radiobuttons).

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form class="addwerkplekinspectie" action="#" method="post">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <p class="inputtitles">Werkplekinspectie template:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <p class="inputtitles nomarginleft">jjjj</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <p class="inputtitles">Titel:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <input type="text" name="titel" class="form-control name_list">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <p class="inputtitles">Inspectienummer:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <input type="text" name="inspectienummer" class="form-control name_list">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <p class="inputtitles">Inspectiedatum:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <input type="date" name="datum" class="form-control name_list">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <p class="inputtitles">Naam inspecteur:</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <input type="text" name="naaminspecteur" class="form-control name_list">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <p class="inputtitles">Locatie/Vestiging</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <input type="text" name="locatie" class="form-control name_list">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <p class="inputtitles">Naam/ Namen geauditeerden</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
         <input type="text" name="naamgeauditeerden" class="form-control name_list">
      </div>
   </div>
   <label class="categorytitle">jjjj</label>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <p class="questionclass">hhhh</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="container text-right">
            <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-1" value="ok">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-1"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-2" value="fout">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-2"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-3" value="nvt">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-3"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <p class="questionclass">jjj</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="container text-right">
            <input type="radio" name="group4" id="radio-4" value="ok">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-4"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="group4" id="radio-5" value="fout">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-5"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="group4" id="radio-6" value="nvt">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-6"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <label class="categorytitle">Testt</label>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
         <p class="questionclass">test</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="container text-right">
            <input type="radio" name="group7" id="radio-7" value="ok">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-7"><span class="radio">Ok</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="group7" id="radio-8" value="fout">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-8"><span class="radio">Fout</span></label>
            <input type="radio" name="group7" id="radio-9" value="nvt">
            <label class="radiotoggle" for="radio-9"><span class="radio">N.v.t</span></label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
<div class="lijstresult">
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg waves-effect btnadd savewpi">Werkplekinspectie opslaan</button>
```

And to give an idea of what I mean this is what my page looks like:

[image]

When I serialize the form and post to my php script the array that I print looks like this (i left everything empty except for the radiobuttons):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => titel
            [value] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => inspectienummer
            [value] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => datum
            [value] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => naaminspecteur
            [value] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => locatie
            [value] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => naamgeauditeerden
            [value] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => group1
            [value] => nvt
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => group4
            [value] => fout
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => group7
            [value] => nvt
        )

)
```

As you can see I have no way of telling which answer belongs to what question and which question belongs to what category.

How can I use the labels (categories) and paragraphs in the form (questions)?

Ideally my array would look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [information] => Array
        (
            [titel] => inserted value
            [inspectienummer] => inserted value
            [datum] => inserted value
            [naaminspecteur] => inserted value
            [locatie] => inserted value
            [naamgeauditeerden] => inserted value
        )

    [questionlist] => Array
        (
            [jjjj] => Array
                    (
                        [hhhh] => ok
                        [jjj] => fout
                    )
            [testt] => Array
                    (
                        [test] => n.v.t.
                    )
        )
)
```

This is how I currently serialize my form:

```
$( ".savewpi" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    url = 'includes/savewpi.php';
    $wpi = $( '.addwerkplekinspectie' ).serializeArray();

    // post the data
    var posting = $.post(url, {
      wpi: $wpi
    });

    console.log($wpi);

    posting.done(function( data ) {
     $( ".lijstresult" ).empty().slideDown('fast').append( data );
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `name` attribute of `input` field to structure your posted data. Create your input fields something like this.

```
<input type="date" name="information[titel]" class="form-control name_list">
<input type="date" name="information[inspectienummer]" class="form-control name_list">
<input type="date" name="information[naaminspecteur]" class="form-control name_list">
<input type="date" name="information[locatie]" class="form-control name_list">
<input type="date" name="information[naamgeauditeerden]" class="form-control name_list">

<input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][hhhh]" id="radio-1" value="ok">
<input type="radio" name="questionlist[jjjj][jjj]" id="radio-2" value="fout">
```